# Examples and suggested principles of designing dissipating usage tracking experiences?

Tags: usability, progress-bar

I was wondering if anyone could assist, I'm not sure what the correct terminology for this is, and therefore struggling to find any research on it.

I'm designing an experience where users have a certain amount of 'uses' of a product, but need some sort of visual indicator in-product that advises of their current usage to understand that once their use amount has dissipated, they can no longer use the product until a certain date, or perhaps further usage will cost extra. Perhaps even indicate their additional usage beyond their given amount somehow. (they are likely to be able to carry on using the product anyway)

I guess a similar example would be data usage.

I'm seeing lots of research and examples on progress tracking, however this is a little different. Can anyone advise of any research I could read on this to advise or inspire, and perhaps some examples of current uses please?

Answer (score 1):

You want to show a basic chart or diagram or progress bar to the user based on the business requirements and user expectation. 
So for tracking data usage, you would display used versus maximum. Since you still let users go over the maximum, the data might still count up but the message will be different.
Other usages might count down to zero, like a bank account or points. So it would disallow any more usage until you buy more.